# Coding idiom for implementing custom collapse/expand behavior in SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have a custom widget (a Group that contains other Composites) that looks like [the top image](https://sites.google.com/site/customcollapseexpandswt/):

I want to implement the behavior that when the user double-clicks on "some text", the widget collapses to something like [the bottom image](https://sites.google.com/site/customcollapseexpandswt/).

If "some text" is double-clicked again, then the widget expands to the original version.

I could implement this by destroying/creating the other widgets inside the green rectangle (i.e., the small text, the rounded rectangle and the circle) and then calling pack() on the green rectangle upon double-click, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant coding idiom for implementing the described behavior? Note: I do not want to use a widget with a designated toggle-button (e.g., a PGroup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `GridLayout` with `GridData` on each item you can use:

```
(GridData)data = (GridData)control.getLayoutData();

data.exclude = true;

control.setVisible(false);
```

to hide a control, when all controls are hidden use `layout()` on the parent composite. To show again reverse the `exclude` and `setVisible` calls.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! This is quite elegant. Is there any way I can decrease the size of the rounded rectangle and circle (they are Image objects), without having to destroy the originals and recreate them with smaller-sized images?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Image object in this context. You could use a `Label` with `setImage` and just switch between two images.

Comment: This works, Greg. I used a similar approach -- a Canvas on which I draw images of different size, depending on whether the widget is in the expanded or the collapsed state. I was just wondering if there is an existing SWT method, e.g., "zoom in/out" that one can use with a single image, instead of swapping different images.